# SQL prepared statements - how to SELECT multiple rows

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have this code so far

```
// Starts the transaction
self::$database->startTransaction();
    try {

        $sql  = "SELECT playerId FROM players WHERE name=?";
        $stmt = self::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $playerName);
        foreach ($playerNames as $key => $playerName) {
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($playerId);
            $stmt->fetch();
            echo $playerId . "<br>";
        }

        // commits the transaction
        self::$database->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        self::$database->rollback();
        throw new Exception(__METHOD__." | ".$e->getMessage());
    }
```

The array `$playerNames` contains the names of the players, e.g.

```
array('Player1', 'Player2', 'player3')
```

The code from above should select the playerId of those players from the database. I have some issues:

1. It just returns the **last** playerId (in this case the Id of 'player3'). I don't know why.
2. I use a `foreach`-loop to `execute()`. is this bad for the performance, if there were hundreds of names in the array?
3. In generell: Is this the correct approach for `SELECT`ing or `INSERT`ing stuff from or into a database?

I read this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

But it didn't really work because of this:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

I get an error with the `getResult()`-method. It says, the method doesn't exist. I think my webspace doesn't support it and I can't install it manually. So I need to stick with `fetch()`.

Or might it have other reasons?

Comment: why do you think there will be hundreds of names?

Comment: I don't know if there will be hundreds of names. Just in case it would be that many, I wanted to ask if there is a better way to improve performance.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: I can't really post **all** of the code. That would be to much. The only thing missing is the database-class which just connects to the database and `self::getConnection()` just returns the connection to the database. Nothing more

Comment: Seems like you are familiar with php, so why don't you just do a step by step deubgging with echo, print_r, var_dump and exit, to find the origin of this issue? should only take a few minutes

Comment: The better way to improve performance is apparently to *avoid* situations where you need to select hundreds of names one by one.

Comment: you're `execute`-ing the query without using the results of that execution. of course it's only going to have the last value.

Comment: Wait a second. That's not fair! I **did** look up the stuff before asking this. I even wrote it! Sorry, but I think this is exaggerated.

Comment: @YourCommonSense what's help-vampire mode? :p

Answer (score 2):

```
    $sql  = "SELECT playerId FROM players WHERE name=?";
    $stmt = self::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $playerName);
    $stmt->bind_result($playerId);
    foreach ($playerNames as $key => $playerName) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo $playerId . "<br>";
    }
```

1. You are fetching results of only last execute
2. Running long loops is apparently bad for performance. Try to avoid them.
3. Yes, in general.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But now I embedded it in my Code and now I get an error like: 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' Because I started a transaction and commited it. If I delete the `commit()` - it works fine. I think it doesn't work because he can't commit more than one query at the time. But how can I fix this? Or shall I post another question?

Comment: You're right :) I just can add `$stmt->store_result();` into the loop

Comment: It suffices to bind the result once.